# Who can give a clear explanation for `combineByKey` in Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark

i am learning spark, but i can't understand this function `combineByKey`.

```
>>> data = sc.parallelize([("A",1),("A",2),("B",1),("B",2),("C",1)] )
>>> data.combineByKey(lambda v : str(v)+"_", lambda c, v : c+"@"+str(v), lambda c1, c2 : c1+c2).collect()
```

The output is:

```
[('A', '1_2_'), ('C', '1_'), ('B', '1_2_')]
```

First, i am very confused: where is the `@` in second step `lambda c, v : c+"@"+v`? i can't find `@` from the result.

Second, i read the function description for `combineByKey`, but i am confused the algorithm flow.

Comment: @eliasah's answer already covers everything. But I suggest you try with different numbers of partitions: `sc.parallelize([("A",1),("A",2),("B",1),("B",2),("C",1)], num_partitions)` With `num_partitions=1` you get `[('A', '1_@2'), ('C', '1_'), ('B', '1_@2')]`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `groupByKey` call makes no attempt at merging/combining values, so it’s an expensive operation.

Thus the `combineByKey` call is just such an optimization. When using `combineByKey` values are merged into one value at each partition then each partition value is merged into a single value. It’s worth noting that the type of the combined value does not have to match the type of the original value and often times it won’t be. The `combineByKey` function takes 3 functions as arguments:

1. A function that creates a combiner. In the `aggregateByKey` function the first argument was simply an initial zero value. In `combineByKey` we provide a function that will accept our current value as a parameter and return our new value that will be merged with additional values.
2. The second function is a merging function that takes a value and merges/combines it into the previously collected values.
3. The third function combines the merged values together. Basically this function takes the new values produced at the partition level and combines them until we end up with one singular value.

In other words, to understand `combineByKey`, it’s useful to think of how it handles each element it processes. As `combineByKey` goes through the elements in a partition, each element either has a key it hasn’t seen before or has the same key as a previous element.

If it’s a new element, `combineByKey` uses a function we provide, called `createCombiner()`, to create the initial value for the accumulator on that key. It’s important to note that this happens the first time a key is found in each partition, rather than only the first time the key is found in the RDD.

If it is a value we have seen before while processing that partition, it will instead use the provided function, `mergeValue()`, with the current value for the accumulator for that key and the new value.

Since each partition is processed independently, we can have multiple accumulators for the same key. When we are merging the results from each partition, if two or more partitions have an accumulator for the same key we merge the accumulators using the user-supplied `mergeCombiners()` function.

**References:**

- Learning Spark - [Chapter 4](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-spark/9781449359034/ch04.html).
- [Using combineByKey in Apache-Spark](http://abshinn.github.io/python/apache-spark/2014/10/11/using-combinebykey-in-apache-spark/) blog entry.

Answer (score 1):

'@' is only added within each partition. In your example, it seems there is only one element in each partition. 
Try:

```
data.combineByKey(lambda v : str(v)+"_", lambda c, v : c+"@"+str(v), lambda c1, c2 : c1+'$'+c2).collect() $
```

and see the difference

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of combineByKey. The objective is to find a per key average of the input data.

```
scala> val kvData = Array(("a",1),("b",2),("a",3),("c",9),("b",6))
kvData: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((a,1), (b,2), (a,3), (c,9), (b,6))

scala> val kvDataDist = sc.parallelize(kvData,5)
kvDataDist: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:26

scala> val keyAverages = kvDataDist.combineByKey(x=>(x,1),(a: (Int,Int),x: Int)=>(a._1+x,a._2+1),(b: (Int,Int),c: (Int,Int))=>(b._1+c._1,b._2+c._2))
keyAverages: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (Int, Int))] = ShuffledRDD[4] at combineByKey at <console>:25

scala> keyAverages.collect
res0: Array[(String, (Int, Int))] = Array((c,(9,1)), (a,(4,2)), (b,(8,2)))

scala> val keyAveragesFinal = keyAverages.map(x => (x._1,x._2._1/x._2._2))
keyAveragesFinal: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at <console>:25

scala> keyAveragesFinal.collect
res1: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((c,9), (a,2), (b,4))
```

combineByKey takes 3 functions as arguments:

1. Function 1 = createCombiner : Called once per key 'k', in each partition

   - Input: Value associated with a key 'k'
   - Output: Any desired output type 'O' based on the program logic. This output type will be automatically used further.
     In this example the output type chosen is (Int,Int). 
     The first element in the Pair sums the values, the second element keeps track of the number of elements that make up the sum.
2. Function 2 = mergeValue : Called as many times as the occurrence of key 'k' within the partition - 1

   - Input: (Output of createCombiner: O, Subsequent value associated with the key 'k' in this partition)
   - Output: (Output: O)
3. Function 3 = mergeCombiners : Called as many times as the partitions in which the key exists

   - Input: (Output of mergeValue from Partition X: O, Output of mergeValue  from partition Y: O)
   - Output: (Output: O )