# How to use combineByKey in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I got a question from HW: 
we have a sample data like this---
data = [ ("B", 2), ("A", 1), ("A", 4), ("B", 2), ("B", 3) ]
the combineByKey code is like this---

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize( data )
>>> rdd2 = rdd.combineByKey
>>> rdd2 = rdd.combineByKey(lambda value: (value, value+2, 1),
... lambda x, value: (x[0] + value, x[1] + value*value, x[2] + 1),
... lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1], x[2] + y[2]))
```

I got a result like this:

```
>>> myoutput = rdd2.collect()
>>> myoutput
[('B', (7, 17, 3)), ('A', (5, 9, 2))]
```

since we suppose to manually write out the answer instead of just run the code to get the result. 
after the first lambda, is it correct I got this result: (b, (2,4,1)), (a,(1,3,1)), (a,(4,6,1)),(b,(2,4,1)),(b,(3,5,1)? But I don't quite understand "x[1] + value*value" part for the second lambda? How to get the middle value of 17 and 9 for b and a?

Can anyone help to explain to me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937625/who-can-give-a-clear-explanation-for-combinebykey-in-spark) by *cricket_007*,

> When using `combineByKey` values are merged into one value at each partition then each partition value is merged into a single value.

Lets first look at the number of partitions and what each partition contains after we `parallelize` the data.

```
>>> data = [ ("B", 2), ("A", 1), ("A", 4), ("B", 2), ("B", 3) ]
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize( data )
>>> rdd.collect()
[('B', 2), ('A', 1), ('A', 4), ('B', 2), ('B', 3)]
```

Number of partitions (by default):

```
>>> num_partitions = rdd.getNumPartitions()
>>> print(num_partitions)
4
```

Contents of each partition:

```py
>>> partitions = rdd.glom().collect()
>>> for num,partition in enumerate(partitions):
...    print(f'Partitions {num} -> {partition}')
Partitions 0 -> [('B', 2)]
Partitions 1 -> [('A', 1)]
Partitions 2 -> [('A', 4)]
Partitions 3 -> [('B', 2), ('B', 3)]
```

`combineByKey` is defined as

```
combineByKey(createCombiner, mergeValue, mergeCombiners, partitioner)
```

The three functions that `combineByKey` takes as arguments,

1. *createCombiner* :`(lambda value: (value, value+2, 1)`
   This will be called on every unseen key in a partition.
2. *mergeValue* : `lambda x, value: (x[0] + value, x[1] + value*value, x[2] + 1)` This will be called when the key is already seen before in a particular partition.
3. *mergeCombiners* : `lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1], x[2] + y[2])`
   This will be called to merge the keys of different partitions
4. *partitioner* : Beyond the scope of this answer.

Now let's work out what happens:

```
Parition 0:  [('B', 2)]
createCombiner
('B', 2) -> Unseen Key -> ('B', (2, 2+2, 1))
                       -> ('B', (2,4,1) 
# Same createCombiner for partition 1,2,3  
Partition 1: [('A',1)]
createCombiner
('A',1) -> Unseen Key -> ('A', (1,3,1))

Partition 2: [('A',4)]
createCombiner
('A',4) -> Unseen Key -> ('A', (4,6,1))

Partition 3: [('B',2), ('B',3)]
createCombiner
('B',2) -> Unseen Key -> ('B',(2,4,1))

('B',3) -> Seen Key -> mergeValue ('B',(2,4,1)) with ('B',3) 
                    -> ('B', (2 + 3, 4+(3*3), 1+1)
                    -> ('B', (5,13,2))

Partition 0 and Partition 3:
mergeCombiners ('B', (2,4,1)) and ('B', (5,13,2))
        -> ('B', (2+5,4+13,1+2))
        -> ('B', (7,19,3)


Partition 1 and 2:
mergeCombiners ('A', (1,3,1)) and ('A', (4,6,1))
        -> ('A', (1+4, 3+6, 1+1))
        -> ('A', (5,9,2))
```

So the final answer that we get is:

```
>>> rdd2 = rdd.combineByKey(lambda value: (value, value+2, 1),
... lambda x, value: (x[0] + value, x[1] + value*value, x[2] + 1),
... lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1], x[2] + y[2]))
>>> rdd2.collect()
[('B', (7, 17, 3)), ('A', (5, 9, 2))]
```

I hope this explains whats going on.

Additional Clarification as asked in comments:

**How does spark set the number of partitions?**

From the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/programming-guide.html#parallelized-collections): *Spark tries to set the number of partitions automatically based on your cluster. However, you can also set it manually by passing it as a second parameter to parallelize (e.g. sc.parallelize(data, 10)*

**How does spark partition the data?**
A partition (aka split) is a logical chunk of a large distributed data set.
Spark has three different partitioning schemes, namely

1. *hashPartitioner* : The Default. Send keys with the same hash module end up on the same node.
2. *customPartitioner* :Example below.
3. *rangePartitioner* : Elements with keys in the same range appear on the same node.

I quote from *Learning Spark by Karau et al.* Pg.61, *that spark does not give you explicit control on which key goes to which partition, but it ensures a set of keys will appear together on some node.* If you want keys with the same value to appear together in the same partition you can use a custom partitioner like so.

```py
>>> def customPartitioner(key):
...    if key == 'A':
...        return 0
...    if key == 'B':
...        return 1
>>> num_partitions = 2 
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize( data ).partitionBy(num_partitions,customPartitioner)
>>> partitions = rdd.glom().collect()
>>> for num,partition in enumerate(partitions):
...    print(f'Partition {num} -> {partition}')
Partition 0 -> [('A', 1), ('A', 4)]
Partition 1 -> [('B', 2), ('B', 2), ('B', 3)]
```

I encourage you to read the book to learn more.

Comment: Thank you so much for such detailed explanation! So if not specified, we use the default 4 partitions? Also, if there are more data, does that mean the 4th partition gets more data, or it's just randomly assigned? Because when I tried to add another set of data, ('A',1), even I didn't change anything of  'B', the result turned to [('B', (7, 13, 3)), ('A', (6, 22, 3))]. The new set of data goes to which partition? Seems partition 3 no longer includes (B,2),(B,3), since the middle value is 13 instead of 17..(Sorry I just started to learn this, so a little confusing)

Comment: @Qing Hi, I have added explanations to your questions. If this is the answer you were looking for, I would appreciate it if you accept my answer. I think you can work out the rest of the math yourself. Thanks!

Comment: I really appreciate, it helps me understand much better. This is the first time I ask question on Stackoverflow, I guess I just voted, but how do I accept your answer?

Comment: @Qing You have accepted my answer. Thank you! :) Voting up is different. You need to click on the up arrow to vote up someone's answer. Here is a helpful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) on how to accept/vote-up an answer.

Comment: Hehe, anyway, thank you for your help!